# Error in FormPagePreviewRenderer.php T3 10.3.0

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

after the update from 10.2 to 10.3 via composer I get the following error at pages with a form at the Page Preview (only there):

```
Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, null given | TypeError thrown in file /public/typo3/sysext/form/Classes/Hooks/FormPagePreviewRenderer.php in line 63
```

Did I miss something during the update or is it due to T3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused by a bug.
Found the solution at https://forge.typo3.org/issues/90598